# How to apply OS update/patch remotely in CentOS EC2 instances?

Tags: linux, centos, patch

I've a bunch of EC2 instances running on CentOS 6.x. Logging into each and updating the OS (yum update) is cumbersome and not efficient. I'm looking for the optimum way of updating these servers remotely through a script (if possible). Probably Chef is a candidate, but I don't have any expertise on it.

What I'm looking is to run these commands in order :

```
yum clean all
yum update -y
reboot
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How do you access the systems? Password? Public key SSH?

Comment: @thrig ... using public key ssh

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for dealing with unattended upgrades in Centos, one of which is: `yum cron`. You'd do well to take a look at the yum-cron [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum-cron.8.html), [this discussion](https://community.centminmod.com/threads/automatic-nightly-yum-updates-with-yum-cron.1507/) on setting it up, as well as [this thread](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1238193) for a discussion on using the tool in a production environment. What's nice about this approach is that once configured, updates on each machine occur independent of one another, and don't run the risk of hiccuping on a failed script.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately,we don't want auto upgrades as it creates unwanted consequences at times. I had seen that auto kernel upgrade disrupted software as they were not compatible.I would rather like to have a control on what we want to update. I'll take a look into the "cron" tool.

Comment: There's a lot of debate on whether or not one should allow auto upgrades and, I suppose, the answer is specific to the use case. I wonder though, what would be the difference between scripting upgrades and letting a tool like `yum cron` or some other automated server management system like Ansible, Chef, or Puppet do it for you (other than the overhead)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the [AWS Systems Manager - Patch Manager service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-patch.html)? They provide a convenient and easy way to keep track of which patches are installed on EC2 Instances and updating them (without having to log in).